# Laravel: Can we use a service of latest version in previous version

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

My application is developed in `Laravel 5.1`. Can I use [Billing module](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing) of laravel `from 5.2` ? I have seen in 5.2 the billing module is quite different and demands different namespaces and interfaces. I have tried to use by upgrading `cashier package` to ~6.0 but it has generated error

```
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Laravel\Cashier\Contracts\Billable' not found in /project/app/Models/User.php on line 8
```

In `Laravel 5.1` with `cashier 4.0`, 
this is how my User Model have following namespaces

```
 <?php namespace App\Models;

  use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
  use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
  use Laravel\Cashier\Contracts\Billable as BillableContract;


 class User extends EloquentUser implements BillableContract
 {
    use Billable;
   /////
 }
```

But when I have upgraded `cashier to ~6.0` it has generated the above mentioned error.

Can we use cashier package of Laravel 5.2 in 5.1, If yes how can I do that?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't response to your email but hope you got the answer :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha Thank you. i got the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dependencies for Cashier 6.0 don't exceed the requirements that Laravel 5.1 can offer, according to the library's [`composer.json`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/d1809efef7513c7666f5eaae0300436c2e65f287/composer.json) file, so you should be able to use Cashier 6.0 with Laravel 5.1. The solution here looks to be very simple, just remove the line with the contract:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Contracts\Billable as BillableContract;
```

And use only the `Billable` trait:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;
```

That's because while Cashier 5.0 had the `Billable` interface [defined in `Contracts`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/tree/1326b42abc5b5c01abf9324efbb67f9ad486d42c/src/Laravel/Cashier), version 6.0 [removed that](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/tree/d1809efef7513c7666f5eaae0300436c2e65f287/src). Also the [Cashier Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing#introduction) for Laravel 5.1 shows how to setup models with Cashier 5 by adding both use statements that you're currently using, while the [Cashier Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#introduction) for Laravel 5.2, which uses Cashier 6, only shows that you need to use the `Billable` trait.

---

There's also one other notable difference between Cashier 4 and 6 dependencies:

- Cashier 4 required [`"stripe/stripe-php": "~1.9"`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/1326b42abc5b5c01abf9324efbb67f9ad486d42c/composer.json#L17)
- Cashier 6 requires [`"stripe/stripe-php": "~3.0"`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/d1809efef7513c7666f5eaae0300436c2e65f287/composer.json#L17)

So make sure that requirement is also satisfied.

Comment: What about class? In 5.1 we have `class User extends EloquentUser implements BillableContract ` and in 5.2 it says for `class User extends Authenticatable`. If I use the later one it shows error, `'class reference expected`?

Comment: Please post your current `User` model class definition code. The contents of the class are not important, only the use statements and class definition.

Comment: Ok, just remove the interface constraint. Since there's no contract anymore, to  there's no more need for `implements BillableContract`